# Does $T (A T)^+ = A^+$ hold for invertible $T$ and full-row-rank $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, pseudoinverse

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be invertible and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ have independent rows. Does the following hold?

$$T (A T)^+ = A^+,$$

where $(\cdot)^+$ gives the M-P inverse.

My proof is given as follows:

Set $B = T (A T)^+$, and we get $A B = (A T) (A T)^+ = I$, i.e., $B = A^+$ which implies $T (A T)^+ = A^+$.

Am I right? Thanks!

PS: What if the condition that $A$ has independent rows is removed?

Comment: Note that $AB = I$ does **not** imply that $B = A^+$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, you are right. The right inverse is not unique. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Products) (case 3), we have
$$
T(AT)^+ = T T^+A^+ = T T^{-1} A^+ = A^+,
$$
which is what we wanted. This uses the fact that $A$ has linearly independent rows, so I am not sure about the more general case.

---

The assumption of independent of rows cannot be dropped. For unit vectors $u,v$ and $A = uv^\top$, we find that $A^+ = vu^\top$ and
$$
T(AT)^+ = \frac{1}{\|T^\top v\|^2}TT^\top vu^\top,
$$
so that the desired equality holds iff we have $v = \frac{TT^\top}{\|T^\top v\|^2} v$; in particular, we see that $v$ must be an eiegnvector of $TT^\top$. This fails to hold, for instance, with
$$
v = (1,1)^\top, \quad T= \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2},
$$
and any choice of $u$.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much for your help :-)